# How to display doc id of results returned by search api in django template?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, full-text-search

I am using app engine search api to search within documents. the results returned are displayed on the django template like this

```
{% for item in results %}
    {{item.id.0.value}}
    {{item.name.0.value}}
{% endfor %}
```

i am able to display all the fields in template except the **doc_id** of the result. can someone please help me to figure how to display doc_id in the template?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/#Python_Putting_documents_in_an_index):

> ...you can examine the id attribute of the result to discover the
>   doc_id that was generated.

So the .id property in your example is in fact the doc_id you are looking for.

Comment: id is another column in my db table.Its not the doc_id that a document has.